# Arduino heart rate sensor bluetooth terminal upon event command

Tags: bluetooth, terminal, command-line

I have an Arduino uno r3 set up as a pulse/heart rate monitor, I have a HC 05 bluetooth module set up so i can connect with my android phone, i get the reading on my android phone in a "heart rate is 86" and it shows a new reading every few seconds. 
Is there a way I can set up an event via the Bluetooth terminal or other app, to make it possible to sound an alarm or other android command upon a specified heart rate.

Comment: what Bluetooth terminal are you talking about?

Comment: Bluetooth Terminal by Qwerty is what i'm using

Comment: Comments are meant to be temporary. Please [edit] your question.